# MS Access SQL - SELECT COUNT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with some entries and i need help with an sql command. 
The Table consists round about 50 entries with 6 columns.

```
Table: tbl-planung

ID SID STATUS ... ... ... 
1  MDT Yes    ... ... ...
2  ABC Yes    ... ... ...
3  BLA NO     ... ... ...
```

I need a command which counts the total amount of entries in that table
+ the amount of entries with `STATUS = Yes`

Like:

```
TOTAL DONE
50    2
```

But my command returns

```
TOTAL DONE
50    50
```

SQL Command

```
SELECT Count([tbl-planung].Abgeschlossen) AS Total, 
       Count([tbl-planung].Abgeschlossen) AS Done
  FROM [tbl-planung]
 WHERE ((([tbl-planung].Abgeschlossen)=Yes));
```

Comment: Wasn't my answer correct ? I replied before juergen and my solution is faster.

Comment: It looks correct but i saw juergens reply first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional SUM

```
SELECT Count(Abgeschlossen) AS Total, 
       sum(iif(Abgeschlossen = Yes, 1, 0)) AS Done
FROM [tbl-planung]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUM instead, without `WHERE`:

```
SELECT Count([tbl-planung].*) AS Total, 
       -Sum([tbl-planung].Abgeschlossen) AS Done
  FROM [tbl-planung]
```